# Dynamic SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am writing a dynamic insert query in a stored procedure. I am receiving the column names as parameter to my stored procedure.

For example, I have an `Employee` table with `EmployeeId` and `EmployeeName` columns. I need to append `EMP_` before each employee name while inserting the data into `Department` table from `Employee` table.

Non-dynamic query looks like this.

```
 INSERT INTO Department(EmployeeId, EmployeeName)
     SELECT 
         EmployeeId, 'EMP_' + EmployeeName
     FROM 
         Employee
```

If I write a dynamic insert

```
 SET @SqlCommand =
          'INSERT INTO ' + @DepartmentTable + '(' + @EmployeeIdColumn + ',' + @EmployeeNameColumn + ')' +
          'SELECT ' + @EmployeeIdColumn + ',''EMP_''' + @EmployeeNameColumn + '''' +     
          'FROM ' +
              @EmployeeTable + ' WTB '  

        EXEC sp_executesql
        @stmt        = @SqlCommand
```

The issue is, for the `EmployeeName` column, it is inserting "EMP_EmployeeName" instead of actual employee name. I tried putting quotes before and after `EmployeeNameColumn`, but it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: append "EMP" before each employee name. @EmployeeNameColumn is the column name, which the stored proc receives.

Comment: Whilst this isn't and answer pre se, I would strongly advise you to read this blog post. I refer back to it anytime  Im doing dynamic sql. It details lots of "best practise" ways to achieve dynamic sql thats both secure (Parameterised) and efficient http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#good_practices

Comment: @turbo88 hey! Have you tried any of solutions provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just one `+` after `EMP_''`, and remove it after `' WTB '`. Also i fixed some spaces:

```
SET @SqlCommand =
'INSERT INTO ' + @DepartmentTable + ' (' + @EmployeeIdColumn + ',' + @EmployeeNameColumn + ')' +
' SELECT ' + @EmployeeIdColumn + ',''EMP_''+' + @EmployeeNameColumn +      
' FROM ' + @EmployeeTable + ' WTB '
```

If you `PRINT @SqlCommand` you will get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Department (EmpId,EmpName) SELECT EmpId,'EMP_'+EmpName FROM Employee WTB
```

And one note: better use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) with table/column names. It will help to avoid situations where column has spaces in the name like 'Employee Name':

```
SET @SqlCommand =
'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@DepartmentTable) + '(' + QUOTENAME(@EmployeeIdColumn) + ',' + QUOTENAME(@EmployeeNameColumn) + ')'+
' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@EmployeeIdColumn) + ',''EMP_''+' + QUOTENAME(@EmployeeNameColumn) + 
' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@EmployeeTable) + ' WTB '
```

To get:

```
INSERT INTO [Department]([EmpId],[EmpName]) SELECT [EmpId],'EMP_'+[EmpName] FROM [Employee] WTB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function.

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse  

CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )
```

Your query would then look like this :

```
INSERT INTO deptTable(empId,empName) 
SELECT empId,concat('EMP_', empName) as empName FROM empTable
```

PS: Looks like I misunderstood your question.

```
INSERT INTO deptTable(empId,empName) 
SELECT empId,'SUFFIX'+empName as empName FROM empTable
```

will also work. I guess you wanted it for the stored proc.

In any case the `concat` should still do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dynamic query to create stored procedure with `insert` statement with columns and parameters

```
> DECLARE @table_name varchar(255) = 'table_name'
>       DECLARE @v_col varchar(MAX)
>       DECLARE @v_param varchar(MAX)
>       DECLARE @SP_param varchar(MAX)
>       DECLARE @sp_type varchar(10) = 'Insert'
>     
>         SET @v_col = STUFF(
>                      (SELECT ',' + '['+c.name+']'
>                      FROM sys.tables t  JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
>                                 WHERE t.name = @table_name
>                                 AND c.is_identity = 0
>                          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
>                             )
>         SET @v_param =  STUFF(
>                          (SELECT ',' + '@'+c.name
>                          FROM sys.tables t  JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
>                                 WHERE t.name = @table_name
>                                 AND c.is_identity = 0
>                          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
>                             )
>     
>         SET @SP_param = STUFF(
>                          (SELECT ',' + '@'+c.name+' '+y.name+' '+(CASE WHEN y.name = 'varchar' THEN '('+CAST(c.max_length as varchar)+')'
> ELSE '' END)
>                          FROM sys.tables t  JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
>                          JOIN sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
>                                 WHERE t.name = @table_name
>                                 AND c.is_identity = 0
>                          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
>                             )
>       Declare @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
>       DECLARE @SPQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
>       SET @SPQuery = 'CREATE PROCEDURE '+@sp_type+''+@table_name+' ('+@SP_param+')
>       AS BEGIN'
>       SET @Query='Insert Into '+@table_name+' ('+@v_col+')
>         Values (
>             '+@v_param+')
>             END'
>     
>     
>       PRINT(@SPQuery); 
>       PRINT(@Query);
```